# Problema con componente COM y servicio WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, com

Tengo que integrar en una API desarrollada en ASP.Net 6 una funcionalidad que se realiza mediante una librería diseñada para tal efecto.
Esta libreria es compatible en un entorno .Net Framework, pero no en .Net 6, por lo que decidí hacer un servicio Windows que me levanta un WCF auto-alojado para así poder consumir sus recursos des de la API Rest.
El servicio WCF es simple y por ahora solo tiene un endPoint, que me retorna el numero a asignar a un parte de trabajo.
La interfaz y el método son estos:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILcOEM
{
    [OperationContract]
    int DameContador();
}

public class LcOEM : ILcOEM
{
    public int DameContador()
    {

        LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM ejecutaOEM = new LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM();
        ejecutaOEM.InicializaOEM(199, "admin", "1234", "", "LOCALHOST\TEST", "ERP");
        return ejecutaOEM.EjecutaOEM("DameContador", "PARTE_TRABAJO", "2023", "-1", "");

    }
}
```

Aquí el servicio:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost _serviceHost;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _serviceHost?.Close();
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8043/DameContador");
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(LcOEM),baseAddress);
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILcOEM), new BasicHttpBinding(),"");

        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
        _serviceHost.Open();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _serviceHost?.Close();
        _serviceHost = null;
    }
}
```

Esto está funcionando correctamente, pero solo la primera vez que consumo el recurso.
Cuando yo consumo el recurso me genera correctamente el contador, pero a la que le digo que me genere otro me reporta la excepción:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set'"

Si hago exactamente lo mismo en un proyecto de WindowsForms funciona perfectamente y me genera los números que sean.
He probado de instanciar el componente a cada petición y nada, he probado también de ejecutarlo en otro hilo, y nada.
La única forma en la que vuelve a generarme un contador es reiniciando el servicio.

Cabe decir que a veces puedo llegar a generar 2 o 3 antes de que empiece a dar problemas.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos.